# How do I make an outgoing socket to a SPECIFIC network interface?

Tags: networking, language-agnostic, ip

I have a server with two different network interfaces, each with a different IP address. How can I create a socket so it'll go out a specific IP address?

I'd prefer a python example, but the question is language agnostic, so shoot away.

EDIT: Please don't give me "You can't" as an answer. I mean, it is a computer. I can do anything I like to it, for example - I can programatically disable the one interface I don't want on the fly. I'm looking for something prettier.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can certainly bind a socket to a specific device.

I don't know how to do it in python, but using the berkeley socket api (in C) you need to call `setsockopt()`, using the option `SO_BINDTODEVICE`.

You pass in an interface descriptor, which is of type `struct ifreq`. Ideally you would get the contents of the interface descriptor by using `ioctl()`, and requesting `SIOCGIFINDEX` - passing the name of the interface (eg. eth0) as an argument.

---

edit: Just did a quick search and found [this](http://pydoc.org/2.4.1/socket.html) documentation of the socket methods in python. `setsockopt()` is amongst them.

Comment: Works for Linux only. What about OS X?

Answer (score 15):

Just a little note - what I really needed is to bind to a specific IP, and just for the sake of completeness, the solution is to bind the socket after creation. Source in python:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
s.bind(("127.0.0.1", 0))
s.connect(("321.12.131.432", 80))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
s.bind((get_ip_address('eth0'), 0))
```

from [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Which-Python-library-allows-us-to-specify-network-interface-to-connect-to-the-Internet)

Comment: This won't work without the definition of get_ip_address