# How to select a network interface for multicasting with python

Tags: python, networking, network-programming

I am using this code to multicast a message with my devices wireless IP address over a Wlan network:

```
import socket

MCAST_GRP = '224.1.1.1'
MCAST_PORT = 5007
IP=''

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.connect(('8.8.8.8', 1))
    IP = s.getsockname()[0]
    print(IP)
    s.close()

except:
    print("Could not get IP")
    s.close()

try:
    udp_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
    udp_socket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, 2)
    udp_socket.sendto(IP, (MCAST_GRP, MCAST_PORT))
    udp_socket.close()
    print("Multicast Message sent.")

except:
    print("Message not sent")
    udp_socket.close()
```

All the devices are connected through a wireless router, and the router allows multicast messages. The code is getting the devices' IP and sending it in a multicast message. The devices have a mix of Linux Debian 8 and Windows 10 OS.

In devices were the only active network interface is wireless, this works straight away. The issue is that sometimes there is more than one active network interface available, and I need to select the wireless one if available. I tried to reduce the values of the metric parameter of the wireless interface and it worked, but I had to do this manually and I need it automated.

[image: IP metric values.]

I would like to know how to complement my code to be able to select the required network interface (hopefully in a portable way), to multicast messages and receive them. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested working with Python 2.7 in Linux Debian 8 and Windows 10.

For Linux:

```
def get_local_wireless_ip_linux():
    import fcntl
    import struct
    import socket
    ifname = 'wlan0'
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    wlan0_ip = (socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(s.fileno(), 0x8915, struct.pack('256s', ifname[:15]))[20:24]))
    return wlan0_ip
```

and for Windows:

```
def get_local_wireless_ip_windows():
    import subprocess
    arp = subprocess.check_output('arp -a')
    local_ipv4 = []
    for line in arp.split('\n'):
        if 'Interface' in line:
            local_ipv4.append(line.split(':')[1].split('---')[0].strip())
    return local_ipv4[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Binding to an IP from the desired interface before connection seems to work for most. The trick is getting that IP.
Further details at 
[Can Python select what network adapter when opening a socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437726/can-python-select-what-network-adapter-when-opening-a-socket)

And [How can I get the IP address of eth0 in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196932/how-can-i-get-the-ip-address-of-eth0-in-python)

Comment: Thank you for leading me in the right direction. After getting the IP address of the desired interfaces In windows and Linux, I used the bind option for the windows interfaces, and the SO_BINDTODEVICE for the Linux interfaces (which requires su or sudo priviledges for execution). All working now, sending and receiving multicast messages in the desired IPs through the required interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to retrieve information of your IPv4/IPv6 network interfaces with the following script. Hope this helps.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from ctypes import *
from sys import platform
from socket import AF_INET, AF_INET6, inet_ntop

try:
    from socket import AF_PACKET
except ImportError:
    AF_PACKET = -1

if platform.startswith("darwin") or platform.startswith("freebsd"):
    AF_LINK = 18
    IFT_ETHER = 0x6
else:
    AF_LINK = -1
    IFT_ETHER = -1


def get_if_addresses():
    """
    Retrieve all relevant information of IPv4/IPv6 network interfaces.
    Based on http://pastebin.com/wxjai3Mw (Author unknown)
    """

    # getifaddr structs
    class ifa_ifu_u(Union):
        _fields_ = [
            ("ifu_broadaddr", c_void_p),
            ("ifu_dstaddr", c_void_p)
        ]

    class ifaddrs(Structure):
        _fields_ = [
            ("ifa_next", c_void_p),
            ("ifa_name", c_char_p),
            ("ifa_flags", c_uint),
            ("ifa_addr", c_void_p),
            ("ifa_netmask", c_void_p),
            ("ifa_ifu", ifa_ifu_u),
            ("ifa_data", c_void_p)
        ]

    # AF_UNKNOWN / generic
    if platform.startswith("darwin") or platform.startswith("freebsd"):
        class sockaddr(Structure):
            _fields_ = [
                ("sa_len", c_uint8),
                ("sa_family", c_uint8),
                ("sa_data", (c_uint8 * 14))
            ]
    else:
        class sockaddr(Structure):
            _fields_ = [
                ("sa_family", c_uint16),
                ("sa_data", (c_uint8 * 14))
            ]

    # AF_INET / IPv4
    class in_addr(Union):
        _fields_ = [
            ("s_addr", c_uint32),
        ]

    if platform.startswith("darwin") or platform.startswith("freebsd"):
        class sockaddr_in(Structure):
            _fields_ = [
                ("sin_len", c_uint8),
                ("sin_family", c_uint8),
                ("sin_port", c_ushort),
                ("sin_addr", in_addr),
                ("sin_zero", (c_char * 8))  # padding
            ]
    else:
        class sockaddr_in(Structure):
            _fields_ = [
                ("sin_family", c_short),
                ("sin_port", c_ushort),
                ("sin_addr", in_addr),
                ("sin_zero",  (c_char * 8))  # padding
            ]

    # AF_INET6 / IPv6
    class in6_u(Union):
        _fields_ = [
            ("u6_addr8", (c_uint8 * 16)),
            ("u6_addr16", (c_uint16 * 8)),
            ("u6_addr32", (c_uint32 * 4))
        ]

    class in6_addr(Union):
        _fields_ = [
            ("in6_u", in6_u),
        ]

    if platform.startswith("darwin") or platform.startswith("freebsd"):
        class sockaddr_in6(Structure):
            _fields_ = [
                ("sin6_len", c_uint8),
                ("sin6_family", c_uint8),
                ("sin6_port", c_ushort),
                ("sin6_flowinfo", c_uint32),
                ("sin6_addr", in6_addr),
                ("sin6_scope_id", c_uint32),
            ]
    else:
        class sockaddr_in6(Structure):
            _fields_ = [
                ("sin6_family", c_short),
                ("sin6_port", c_ushort),
                ("sin6_flowinfo", c_uint32),
                ("sin6_addr", in6_addr),
                ("sin6_scope_id", c_uint32),
            ]

    # AF_PACKET / Linux
    class sockaddr_ll(Structure):
        _fields_ = [
            ("sll_family", c_uint16),
            ("sll_protocol", c_uint16),
            ("sll_ifindex", c_uint32),
            ("sll_hatype", c_uint16),
            ("sll_pktype", c_uint8),
            ("sll_halen", c_uint8),
            ("sll_addr", (c_uint8 * 8))
        ]

    # AF_LINK / BSD|OSX
    class sockaddr_dl(Structure):
        _fields_ = [
            ("sdl_len", c_uint8),
            ("sdl_family", c_uint8),
            ("sdl_index", c_uint16),
            ("sdl_type", c_uint8),
            ("sdl_nlen", c_uint8),
            ("sdl_alen", c_uint8),
            ("sdl_slen", c_uint8),
            ("sdl_data", (c_uint8 * 46))
        ]

    if platform.startswith("darwin"):
        libc = CDLL("libSystem.dylib")

    elif platform.startswith("freebsd"):
        libc = CDLL("libc.so")

    else:
        libc = CDLL("libc.so.6")

    ptr = c_void_p(None)
    result = libc.getifaddrs(pointer(ptr))
    if result:
        return None
    ifa = ifaddrs.from_address(ptr.value)
    result = []

    while ifa:
        # Python 2 gives us a string, Python 3 an array of bytes
        if type(ifa.ifa_name) is str:
            name = ifa.ifa_name
        else:
            name = ifa.ifa_name.decode()

        if ifa.ifa_addr:
            sa = sockaddr.from_address(ifa.ifa_addr)

            data = {}

            if sa.sa_family == AF_INET:
                if ifa.ifa_addr is not None:
                    si = sockaddr_in.from_address(ifa.ifa_addr)
                    data['addr'] = inet_ntop(AF_INET, si.sin_addr)
                if ifa.ifa_netmask is not None:
                    si = sockaddr_in.from_address(ifa.ifa_netmask)
                    data['netmask'] = inet_ntop(AF_INET, si.sin_addr)

                # check if a valid broadcast address is set and retrieve it
                # 0x2 == IFF_BROADCAST
                if ifa.ifa_flags & 0x2:
                    si = sockaddr_in.from_address(ifa.ifa_ifu.ifu_broadaddr)
                    data['broadcast'] = inet_ntop(AF_INET, si.sin_addr)

            if sa.sa_family == AF_INET6:
                if ifa.ifa_addr is not None:
                    si = sockaddr_in6.from_address(ifa.ifa_addr)
                    data['addr'] = inet_ntop(AF_INET6, si.sin6_addr)

                    if data['addr'].startswith('fe80:'):
                        data['scope'] = si.sin6_scope_id

                if ifa.ifa_netmask is not None:
                    si = sockaddr_in6.from_address(ifa.ifa_netmask)
                    data['netmask'] = inet_ntop(AF_INET6, si.sin6_addr)

            if sa.sa_family == AF_PACKET:
                if ifa.ifa_addr is not None:
                    si = sockaddr_ll.from_address(ifa.ifa_addr)
                    addr = ""
                    total = 0
                    for i in range(si.sll_halen):
                        total += si.sll_addr[i]
                        addr += "%02x:" % si.sll_addr[i]
                    addr = addr[:-1]
                    if total > 0:
                        data['addr'] = addr

            if sa.sa_family == AF_LINK:
                dl = sockaddr_dl.from_address(ifa.ifa_addr)

                if dl.sdl_type == IFT_ETHER:
                    addr = ""
                    for i in range(dl.sdl_alen):
                        addr += "%02x:" % dl.sdl_data[dl.sdl_nlen + i]

                    addr = addr[:-1]
                    data['addr'] = addr

            if len(data) > 0:
                iface = {}
                for interface in result:
                    if name in interface.keys():
                        iface = interface
                        break
                if iface:
                    iface[name][sa.sa_family] = data
                else:
                    iface[name] = { sa.sa_family : data }
                    result.append(iface)

        if ifa.ifa_next:
            ifa = ifaddrs.from_address(ifa.ifa_next)
        else:
            break

    libc.freeifaddrs(ptr)
    return result
```