# Python Paramiko SSH script that use specific IP source

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, juniper

I have currently written this script which works fine, but has a limitation,
I can't decide which source IP can open SSH with the server.
For routers with multiple interfaces it would be extremely useful.
I read that `sock` or `channel` could be used, but
I don't know how to implement them and I can't find examples.

Thanks!

```
from junos import Junos_Context
import paramiko
from datetime import datetime
import jcs

user = Junos_Context['user-context']['login-name']
hostname = Junos_Context['hostname']
now = datetime.now()
day = now.strftime('%Y%m%d')
hour = now.strftime('%H%M%S')

#Sets up the ssh session and logs in as login "simone" with password "simone"
#to host '192.168.2.2' 

host = '192.168.2.2'
login = 'simone'
passw = 'simone'

try:
   ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
   ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
   ssh.connect(host, username=login, password=passw, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
  chan = ssh.invoke_shell()
except:
   print "Login to %s failed" % (host,)
   chan = False

if chan:
   sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
   sftp.put('/config/juniper.conf.gz',
  '/simone/backups/%s_%s_%s_%s_juniper.conf.gz' % (user,hostname,day,hour))

   sftp.close()
   ssh.close()

   print "All it's OK %s ! " % (user,)

else:
   print "Sorry, there is no connection to the host %s" % (host,)
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok, now it works!
Many thanks!
My script finaly is:

> ```
> sok = socket.socket()
> sok.bind((local_address, 0))
> sok.connect((host, 22))
>
> ssh.connect(host, username=login, password=passw, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False, sock=sok)
> ```

Comment: Sorry, but you have just copied my answer. If my answer has helped you, please accept my answer, instead of copied it.

Comment: I'm Sorry, buy your line "s = socks.socksocket()" in my script throws an error. It's true that I only had to change that, but in the end it works as I reported.

Comment: Then if would be nice, if you commented on the typo instread.

Answer (score 4):

Use `sock` argument of [`SSHClient.connect`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect) to provide your customized socket bound to the source address of your choice. Based on [Can Python select what network adapter when opening a socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8437726/850848), this should do:

```
import socket
```

```
s = socks.socket()
s.bind((local_address, 0))
s.connect((host, 22))
ssh.connect(
    host, username=login, password=passw, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False, sock=s)
```